# How to Simplify the Term $(\sum_i x_i y_i)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the term $(\sum_i x_i y_i)^2$ which I want to simplify.
I am pretty sure it should be something like:

$$(\sum_i x_i y_i)^2 = \sum_i x_i^2 y_i^2 + a$$

Where $a$ involves the cross terms.
I am after what would be $a$.

Comment: You are wrong, that formula can't be more simplified.

Comment: @Dominique, Should I have used a different term? I meant to what was done in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do is
$$
\left( \sum_i x_i y_i \right)^2 = \sum_i x_i^2 y_i^2 + 2 \sum_{i < j} x_i y_i x_j y_j = \sum_i x_i^2 y_i^2 + \sum_{i \neq j} x_i y_i x_j y_j.
$$